# How to plot multiple plots associated to different colors of a colorbar with pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots, multiple-files

**I HAVE EDITED THIS THREAD, NEW QUESTION AT THE END**

First of all, I apologize for my possibly bad English as it is not my mother tongue.

My problem is complex but I am going to try to explain it the best I can. Don't hesitate to ask more information if there is something you don't understand.

I have several data files and each file corresponds to one set of marks to plot. Those data were computed by modifying the numerical value of a parameter of my system called k_v (ranging from 0 to 1) in the definition of my function.
I want the colorbar (on the right) to display the values of the parameter k_v (not the y-axis!) and I want each plot to have a different color, corresponding to the color of the parameter k_v that is displayed in the colorbar on the right.

I have 2 problems:

1. I want to use "marks only". If I don't, it works, but as soon as I use "marks only" every mark becomes black and I don't understand why.
2. Right now I use a "trick" so that I don't have to add a "addplot..." command for each plot (I have more than 100 plots in the original document) and I use this to create the y axis of the colorbar.
   However, as I said before, my parameter k_v goes from 0 to 1 (and not from 1 to 4 as it currently does), so for this to work as intended, I should use the command "\foreach \m in {0.25,0.50,...,1}" instead of "\foreach \m in {1,...,4}" and I should rename my data files "data_0.25.dat", "data_0.50.dat", etc... however this won't work as I use a "." before the extension of the file and latex doesn't understand. Do you have any idea on how I could avoid this while still having a "\foreach \m in {1,...,4}" trick?

for the sake of simplification, let's use this code here:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

% *** PACKAGES ***
\usepackage{standalone} % Pour les stand-alone
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} % 68 dvips colors à déclarer avant tikz
\usepackage{tikz} % Pour les figure Tikz
\usepackage{pgfplots} % Pour tracer les courbes à partir de fichiers de données
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % Pour pouvoir lire les tableaux des fichiers .txt
\usepackage{filecontents} % Pour créer des fichiers .dat
% *** PACKAGES END ***

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10} % pour définir la version de pgfplots

\begin{filecontents}{data_1.dat}
-10 0
-8 3
-8 -3
-5 1
-5 -1
\end{filecontents}
%
\begin{filecontents}{data_2.dat}
-8 0
-7.5 2.5
-7.5 -2.5
-4.5 0.8
-4.5 -0.8
\end{filecontents}
%
\begin{filecontents}{data_3.dat}
-6.5 0
-7 2
-7 -2
-4.25 0.6
-4.25 -0.6
\end{filecontents}
%
\begin{filecontents}{data_4.dat}
-5.25 0
-6.75 1.75
-6.75 -1.75
-4 0.4
-4 -0.4
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{mark options={mark size=1.5, line width=0.3pt}}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
        colorbar,
        colorbar style={ylabel=$k_v$-value},%,ytick={0,0.2,...,1}},
        width=0.7\textwidth,
  height=0.6\textwidth,
        grid=major,
        minor x tick num=1,
  xlabel={Real($\lambda (A)$)},
        minor y tick num=1,
  ylabel={Imag($\lambda (A)$)},
        tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
    ]

\foreach \m in {1,...,4}
    {\edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot[mesh,only marks,point meta=\m] table             {data_\m.dat};}\temp}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

This is an example of what I want (this was plotted using matlab)
[image]

Thank you very much for your help

**EDIT:** Ok I figured it wasn't the right approach, so instead I added a third column to each data file. This third column corresponds to the "point meta". If I add manually every plot, it works like a charm. However, I have more than 100 plots so I want to do it automatically using the command

```
\foreach \m in {1,...,4}
{\edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot+[mark=*,only marks,scatter,point meta={\thisrow{k_v}},] table {data_\m.dat};}\temp}
```

Problem is, \thisrow doesn't seem to work in this case. Do anyone knows how to avoid this problem?

Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

% *** PACKAGES ***
\usepackage{standalone} % Pour les stand-alone
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} % 68 dvips colors à déclarer avant tikz
\usepackage{tikz} % Pour les figure Tikz
\usepackage{pgfplots} % Pour tracer les courbes à partir de fichiers de données
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % Pour pouvoir lire les tableaux des fichiers .txt
\usepackage{filecontents} % Pour créer des fichiers .dat
% *** PACKAGES END ***

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12} % pour définir la version de pgfplots

\begin{filecontents}{data_1.dat}
x y k_v
-10 0 0.25
-8 3 0.25
-8 -3 0.25
-5 1 0.25
-5 -1 0.25
\end{filecontents}
%
\begin{filecontents}{data_2.dat}
x y k_v
-8 0 0.50
-7.5 2.5  0.50
-7.5 -2.5  0.50
-4.5 0.8  0.50
-4.5 -0.8  0.50
\end{filecontents}
%
\begin{filecontents}{data_3.dat}
x y k_v
-6.5 0 0.75
-7 2 0.75
-7 -2 0.75
-4.25 0.6 0.75
-4.25 -0.6 0.75
\end{filecontents}
%
\begin{filecontents}{data_4.dat}
x y k_v
-5.25 0 1
-6.75 1.75 1
-6.75 -1.75 1
-4 0.4 1
-4 -0.4 1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{mark options={mark size=1.5, line width=0.5pt}}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    colorbar,
    colorbar style={ylabel=$k_v$-value},%,ytick={0,0.2,...,1}},
    width=0.7\textwidth,
            height=0.6\textwidth,
    grid=major,
    minor x tick num=1,
            xlabel={Real($\lambda (A)$)},
    minor y tick num=1,
            ylabel={Imag($\lambda (A)$)},
    tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
]

\foreach \m in {1,...,4}
{\edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot+[mark=*,only marks,scatter,point meta={\thisrow{k_v}},]         table {data_\m.dat};}\temp}


    \addplot+[mark=*,only marks,scatter,point meta={\thisrow{k_v}},] table {data_1.dat};
    \addplot+[mark=*,only marks,scatter,point meta={\thisrow{k_v}},] table {data_2.dat};
    \addplot+[mark=*,only marks,scatter,point meta={\thisrow{k_v}},] table {data_3.dat};
    \addplot+[mark=*,only marks,scatter,point meta={\thisrow{k_v}},] table {data_4.dat};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For first use `\addplot+[mesh,...` Note `+`. For second, I am working.

Comment: You could put the color (droop parameter) in a third column and use a scatter plot, possibly merging all the files into one.

Comment: Yes John, that's what I did (see the EDIT part of the OP), however I have a new problem when I try to automate the plots: the \thisrow doesn't seem to work in "\foreach \m in {1,...,4}..." and I don't understand why

Comment: I wrote my comment before the correction (time overlap).  If you added column names in the first row you could use something like \addplot+[scatter,scatter src=explicit]
table[x=xcolname,y=ycolname,meta=colordata]
{datafile.dat} (page 104).

Answer (score 3):

My original suggestion was to merge all the data files into one.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

% *** PACKAGES ***
\usepackage{standalone} % Pour les stand-alone
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} % 68 dvips colors à déclarer avant tikz
\usepackage{tikz} % Pour les figure Tikz
\usepackage{pgfplots} % Pour tracer les courbes à partir de fichiers de données
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % Pour pouvoir lire les tableaux des fichiers .txt
\usepackage{filecontents} % Pour créer des fichiers .dat
% *** PACKAGES END ***

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12} % pour définir la version de pgfplots

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
x y k_v
-10 0 0.25
-8 3 0.25
-8 -3 0.25
-5 1 0.25
-5 -1 0.25
-8 0 0.50
-7.5 2.5  0.50
-7.5 -2.5  0.50
-4.5 0.8  0.50
-4.5 -0.8  0.50
-6.5 0 0.75
-7 2 0.75
-7 -2 0.75
-4.25 0.6 0.75
-4.25 -0.6 0.75
-5.25 0 1
-6.75 1.75 1
-6.75 -1.75 1
-4 0.4 1
-4 -0.4 1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{mark options={mark size=1.5, line width=0.5pt}}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    colorbar,
    colorbar style={ylabel=$k_v$-value},%,ytick={0,0.2,...,1}},
    width=0.7\textwidth,
            height=0.6\textwidth,
    grid=major,
    minor x tick num=1,
            xlabel={Real($\lambda (A)$)},
    minor y tick num=1,
            ylabel={Imag($\lambda (A)$)},
    tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
]
\addplot+[only marks,scatter,scatter src=explicit] table[x=x,y=y,meta=k_v] {data.dat};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: scatter plot]

A second solution consisted of removing the `_` character from the file names.  Sometime you can get away from it, but obviously not when including a macro as part of the name.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to merge all the data to one file. The trick is to use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` instead of `\foreach` which allows expansion. Here the code which gives the same resulting image as in [the answer of John Kormylo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273243/95441).

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{filecontents}{data_1.dat}
    x y k_v
    -10 0 0.25
    -8 3 0.25
    -8 -3 0.25
    -5 1 0.25
    -5 -1 0.25
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data_2.dat}
    x y k_v
    -8 0 0.50
    -7.5 2.5  0.50
    -7.5 -2.5  0.50
    -4.5 0.8  0.50
    -4.5 -0.8  0.50
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data_3.dat}
    x y k_v
    -6.5 0 0.75
    -7 2 0.75
    -7 -2 0.75
    -4.25 0.6 0.75
    -4.25 -0.6 0.75
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data_4.dat}
    x y k_v
    -5.25 0 1
    -6.75 1.75 1
    -6.75 -1.75 1
    -4 0.4 1
    -4 -0.4 1
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
    \tikzset{
        mark options={
            mark size=1.5,
            line width=0.3pt,
        },
    }
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        colorbar,
        colorbar style={
            ylabel=$k_v$-value,
        },
        width=0.7\textwidth,
        height=0.6\textwidth,
        grid=major,
        minor x tick num=1,
        xlabel={Real($\lambda (A)$)},
        minor y tick num=1,
        ylabel={Imag($\lambda (A)$)},
        tick label style={
            font=\footnotesize,
        },
    ]
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach {1,...,4} {
            \addplot [
                only marks,
                scatter,
                scatter src=explicit,
            ] table [x=x,y=y,meta=k_v] {data_#1.dat};
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```