# How to include standard error of the slope in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I am trying to include the **standard error of the slope** as

> "slope +- error...> 1.65 +- 0.017"

and also **a line fit** instead of

> mark=x

over the log-log plot. But I cannot calculate the error and show a lint fit instead of `mark=x`. Please help me to do it.

============================

**My code is:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{main-data.dat}
0   1
1   7
2   15
3   27
4   39
5   59
6   73
7   97
8   113
9   133
10  152
11  176
12  207
13  243
14  268
15  298
16  332
17  368
18  398
19  429
20  469
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{slope-data.dat}
 8  113
 9  133
 10 152
 11 176
 12 207
 13 243
 14 268
 15 298
 16 332
 17 368
 18 398
 19 429
 20 469
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\centering
\pgfplotsset{every  major tick/.style={black,},minor y tick num=1}
\pgfplotstableread{slope-data.dat}\datatable
%   
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.4]
\begin{loglogaxis}[
axis background/.style={
shade,top color=gray!60,bottom color=white},
legend style={fill=white,font=\scriptsize, at={(0.96,0.10)},anchor=south east},
tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
label style={font=\footnotesize},
legend cell align=left,
xlabel={$a$},
ylabel={$N(a)$},
legend entries={$r = 0.50-M=2^{0}$, $ d_\mathrm{f} = 
\pgfmathprintnumber{\slope} \pm $},
] 
%   
\addplot+[mark=halfcircle*,only marks,every mark/.append style={rotate=90}]
table[font=\scriptsize] {main-data.dat};
%
\addplot+[mark=x,mark repeat=5,mark phase=6,smooth] 
table[y={create col/linear regression={y=1}}]{\datatable}         
coordinate [pos=0.3] (A) 
coordinate [pos=0.69] (B);
% store slope
\xdef\slope{\pgfplotstableregressiona}
\draw [red,thick] (A) |- (B)  
node[anchor=east,font=\scriptsize,red] at (3.33,7.8)  
{$\sim$\pgfmathprintnumber{\slope}};
%   
\end{loglogaxis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Figure]

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! I get `! Package pgfplots Error: input table 'slope_data.dat' has an unbalanced number
 of columns in row '4' (expected '2' cols; got '1'). Maybe the input table is c
orrupted? If you need unbalanced data, consider using 'nan' in empty cells (per
haps combined with 'unbounded coords=jump').` when I try to run your file.

Comment: @marmot thank you so much. I did not have any errors after compiling the code!!

Comment: Unfortunately the links to the data files don't seem to work any more. Thus, we are not able to reproduce your problem any more. It would be much better if you would edit your question again and add (parts of) your data directly into the code as e.g. shown at <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/291132/95441>. For now I will be voting to close your question until an update. Then I/we will be happy to reopen it.

Comment: @Stefan, my files are too long and I have changed the links for downloading.

Comment: @Stefan, I did it.

Comment: Thank you for that. But I cannot figure out what exactly you want to do. Could you add an image of the current result and sketch the missing parts on that?

Comment: @StefanPinnow I want to (1) calculate standard error for the slope and show it, (2) and also change the type of mark and show it over the blue graph with a line. I have inserted a figure.

Answer (score 1):

*This is more a comment then an answer, but a bit lengthy for that ...*

LaTeX actually is a **typesetting program** rather then a **calculation program**. Although you can do very much with LaTeX and Friends for this task I would recommend doing the calculation elsewhere and only print the *results* with LaTeX/TikZ/PGFPlots.

Thus you could do the following using [gnuplot](/questions/tagged/gnuplot):

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
    \begin{filecontents}{main-data.dat}
        0   1
        1   7
        2   15
        3   27
        4   39
        5   59
        6   73
        7   97
        8   113
        9   133
        10  152
        11  176
        12  207
        13  243
        14  268
        15  298
        16  332
        17  368
        18  398
        19  429
        20  469
    \end{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{slope-data.dat}
         8  113
         9  133
         10 152
         11 176
         12 207
         13 243
         14 268
         15 298
         16 332
         17 368
         18 398
         19 429
         20 469
    \end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{loglogaxis}[
        xlabel={$a$},
        ylabel={$N(a)$},
        legend pos=south east,
        legend cell align=left,
    ]

        \addplot+ [
            mark=halfcircle*,
            only marks,
            every mark/.append style={rotate=90},
        ] table {main-data.dat};

        \addplot [
            red,
            % use gnuplot to calculate the parameters of the straight line
            % including the corresponding error values
            raw gnuplot,
        ] gnuplot {
            % initialize variables
            a = 1;
            b = 1;
            % define fit function
            f(x) = a*x + b;
            % fit variables using log-log values of table data
            fit f(x) 'slope-data.dat' using (log($1)):(log($2)) via a,b;
            % a (straight) line only needs two samples
            set samples 2;
            % plot the result
            plot [x=8:20] exp(f(log(x)));
        };

        \legend{
            $r = 0.50 - M = 2^{0}$,
            $d_\mathrm{f} =
                % add numbers given in 'fit.log'
                \pgfmathprintnumber{1.58617}
                \pm \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{0.0183}$,
        }
    \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. But I want to calculate the error with pgfplot not gnuplot.  Is there a specific calculation for the error using pgfplot like     **pgfplotstableregressiona**. And also about the red line for fitting, I want to fit over the data and the red line should be over the data not under it.

Comment: @AlirezaAlipour I don't think `pgfplots` calculates that error, so you would have do it manually. For the second part, add `clip mode=individual` as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84650/

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.